# E: unable to locate package libopenmpi-dbg

Tags: ubuntu

First, i have a "16.04 LTS" version of ubuntu. 
When i run the command "sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dbg", unfortunately that note "E: unable to locate package libopenmpi-dbg" show to me and the package no installed.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no libopenmpi-dbg was last packaged for precise (12.04), so if you really require libopenmpi-dbg, Debian does provide this package.

Likely installing the Debian package will work.

Just be very careful about this.

When I install Debian packages on Ubuntu systems, I download only the one .deb file I require, rather than setting up a Debian repository, as sometimes setting up Debian repositories causes problems with co-mingled Ubuntu + Debian packages.

Better to only download the exact .deb files you require, so you can deinstall them easily.

Comment: On debian the package is only available for debian Wheezy , if you try to install it on a higher distro you will get Unmet dependencies error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see by what name is the package referenced.

For that, do the following...

```
sudo apt-cache search libopenmpi
```

If there's nothing listed in there, you will have to add the specific repo to the list of repositories OR you can install the package for Debian from the net and install it manually by running appropriate command.